# C#: Visibility of controls

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm stucked with a problem and without proper search keyword I wasn't able to find anything useful.

In my forms Controls property there are: TextBoxes, Buttons, CheckBoxes and a ListBox.They are on a panel (default_panel). There's another panel called: link_panel. I thought it's worth remembering.

So, when I click on menu button a Show***() runs, first hiding all Controls.

```
Form1 hd = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["form1"];
foreach (Control c in hd.Controls)
{
c.Visible = false;
}
```

And then this Show***() starts to enable (make visible) the needed Controls.

```
hd.box1.Visible = true;
hd.box2.Visible = true;
hd.label1.Visible = true;
hd.label1.Text = "Sample Text";
```

The problem comed when I only need the box1 in the another Show***(). The box2 won't became invisible. If I try do like:

```
TextBox tb = c as TextBox;
tb.Visible = false;
```

This comes with NullReferenceExecption (I know what this means). But when I do simple as the first code runs without any problem (only this little bug).

There are to many Controls in a panel to handle separetly.

So for more accuracy:

> There are to two labels "enabled" on the panel.

```
    public void ShowCharacterTable()
    {
        Form1 hd = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["form1"];
        foreach (Control c in hd.Controls)
        {
                c.Visible = false;
        }
        hd.label1.Visible = true;
        hd.label2.Visible = true;
```

So an example method is here.

> There should be only one, but both of them are visible.

```
public void ShowRelationTable()
    {

        Form1 hd = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["form1"];
        foreach (Control c in hd.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
            {
                c.Visible = false;
            }

        }
        hd.label1.Visible = true;
}
```

Ps.: If I remember correctly, it worekd before I added the panels.

Comment: Your code has syntax errors (e.g. `Form1 hd = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["form1];`). Please edit your question to address them.

Comment: Why are you even casting? `Visible` is defined in `Control`, there is no need to cast to `TextBox`. If you are casting to see if  `c` is a `TextBox` then simply check before trying to assign a value to `Visible`: `if (c is TextBox) { c.Visible = false; }`. If `c` is `null` then its obviously not a `TextBox` and you should continue iterating (i'm guessing `c` comes from a `foreach`... a lot of guessing here, your question is missing quite some information)

Comment: `c` is obviously not a `TextBox` hence it's null...

Comment: If you want only `TextBoxes` then you can use `hd.Controls.OfType<TextBox>` and you should not get the `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: I don't get it guys. I tried the if statment by InBetween it didn't turn of the textbox. I edit my question to be more accurate.

Comment: What on earth does this question have to do with the `sql` tag?

Comment: Added accidently, although this is a database application. (Power of Rutin)

Answer (score 0):

It is hd.default_panel.Controls.

```
Form1 hd = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["form1"];
foreach (Control c in hd.panel_default.Controls)
{
  c.Visible = false;
}
```